# Test list for undesired integer

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a list

```
list1 = [0,1,0,0]
```

How can I create an if statement that prints "Failed!" if a "1" is in the list but continues otherwise?

Other examples

```
list2 = [1,1,0,0]
list3 = [0,0,0,0]
```

And there can be more or less integers in the list.

Answer (score 9):

To test for an object in a list, simply use the syntax `if x in my_list:` where x is the thing you are testing for like 1 or 0.

Answer (score 4):

[any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) returns True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

Assuming you want to display "Failed" only once and there are only 0s and 1s:

```
if any(listname):
    print "Failed"
```

It's clean and easily readable. If there are some other integers, `if 1 in listname` will be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

if it's only 0's and 1's you could use `if sum(listname) > 0: print "Failed"`

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you simply use

```
if 1 in list_name: 
    print 'failed'
    //break here if you want 
else:
    //continue your code`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count how many times does an item appear in the list, you should use "count". For example:

```
>> a = [1,2,3,3,2,2]
>> a.count(2)
3
```